# Better half of the decade

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

> He has been working on it for the better half of the decade.

What does this sentence suggest?

Comment: I've edited in "the" before "better", because I'm sure that wasn't what you were asking about (if you *were*, I'd say it suggests the original writer wasn't a native speaker! :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, *the better half* is a somewhat non-standard variant of...

> [**best** part of something](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/best+part+of+something) *- nearly all of something, the majority, most*

...so really all it means here is *for more than five years*. Or feasibly, *for more than 15 months* if we assume by *the decade* he means the period of ten years starting from 2012 (which I seriously doubt! :).

Usually, *the* (or *my*) [*better half*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/better+half) is a slang/ironic term for one's wife (sometimes husband).

Comment: Just FYI, I don't consider *my better half* to be predominantly British at all; I've heard it quite often all my life and it sounds perfectly American to me as well. Perhaps it's a region thing here, but I hear it in songs and movies all the time as well, so it seems at least acceptably common. Anyway, great answer. +1!

Comment: @WendiKidd: I did a bit of checking just now, and I see you're quite right - it's equally common everywhere. Actually, I'd originally intended to write *(mainly BrE **I think**)*, but I dithered because I intended to check it *then*. But I got distracted, obviously. I'll edit out the tattered remnants of a discredited guess, ty! But you being American, *your* better half (assumiong you've got one! :) probably wouldn't be British anyway. We tend to marry within our own tribes!

Comment: Strange - by my reckoning, I've picked up a downvote *since* removing that erroneous *better half **is BrE*** aside. I find it hard to believe someone thinks [better half of the decade](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22better+half+of+the+decade%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) **isn't** a "somewhat non-standard variant". That link is to 6 instances in print, compared to over 5000 for [best part of the decade](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22best+part+of+the+decade%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (in almost all cases they both just mean ***most of***).

Comment: now I am sure the author meant five years

Comment: @Birju Shah: You mean ***more than** five years* (usually, nearer ten than five).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd agree with your *somewhat nonstandard* comment. I think it's possibly because there's a slightly different implication; to my ear at least, when talking about time, the *better half of the decade* more strongly implies something close-to-yet-greater-than half, while the *best part of the decade* is simply any amount greater than half, with a bit of an implication that it's closer to *all of* than *half of*. Not sure why you got a downvote, but four others disagree with the downvoter, so I suppose they're in the minority :)

Comment: I suppose if you really do think there's a distinction in *meaning* between *better half of the decade* and *best half of the decade*, I can't really argue (to all intents and purposes, words mean whatever the speaker intends them to mean). But I think given barely one in a thousand written instances use the former at all (whatever they might mean), it seems to me I was being circumspect to even call it ***somewhat** non-standard*. Also note that it was easy to link to a dictionary definition of the standard version, but I doubt you'd find OP's version in any dictionary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes more than five for sure because I read it on the website of some content writing company and they had stated "we have been working in this field for the better half of the decade" so they must be meaning ***more than five years***

Comment: @Birju Shah: The "non-standard variant" under consideration is perfectly comprehensible to native speakers, but it wouldn't surprise me in the least to discover that the author of that website was *not* in fact a native speaker. Relatively speaking, it's a *very* uncommon usage.